# How to pipe awaited async values through streams in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stream

[Disclaimer: This is my very first shot at Node (I am mostly a Clojure guy)]

I am parsing and transforming a CSV file with [node-csv](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv). The transform happens with IO over the wire and I wrapped the callback with a async/await construct.

```
const in_stream  = fs.createReadStream('test-data')
const out_stream = fs.createWriteStream('test-output')

const parse = csv.parse({ delimiter: "\t", quote: false })

const transform = csv.transform(async (row) => {
    await translate(row[1], { from: 'en', to: 'fr' })
        .then(res => { row[1] = res.text})
    console.log(row) // this shows that I succesfully wait for and get the values
    return row
})

const stringify = csv.stringify({
    delimiter: ';',
    quoted: true 
})

in_stream.pipe(parse).pipe(transform).pipe(stringify).pipe(out_stream)
```

It appears that the stream ends before the values are piped out of the transformer.

How do you deal with delayed values in streams in Node.js? I am obviously getting it wrong…

(I can provide a dummy CSV file if it helps)

Comment: can you try ```
const transform = csv.transform(async (row) => {
    return await translate(row[1], { from: 'en', to: 'fr' });
})```

Comment: @user269867, Thanks. That, unfortunately, did not do it.  (With the `return` it doesn't even run the `log` statement, nor does it return the row :( )

Comment: Well I was trying this code at my end but I got google translation API key error so I think I can't run it to debug further at my end but some quick debug would be adding on ``` transform.on('error', function(err) {
    return logger.error(err);
}); ``` to catch the error

Comment: @user269867, Oh, thanks. If you're interested in using the google translate serivce, you'll need to use a this fork `@vitalets/google-translate-api`.

Comment: can you share me a sample csv

Comment: @user269867, sure: https://gist.github.com/i-blis/7f9c014651ba59c74528523635efafc9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is your `transform` function

```js
const transform = csv.transform(async (row) => {
    await translate(row[1], { from: 'en', to: 'fr' })
        .then(res => { row[1] = res.text})
    console.log(row) // this shows that I succesfully wait for and get the values
    return row
})
```

What you are doing here is assuming the `async` can be just used without any implications. The issue is because you don't actually return anything from your async function in the expected callback, what gets passed to later functions is nothing

The fix is simple, pass the data back in the callback function

```js
const transform = csv.transform(async (row, done) => {
    await translate(row[1], { from: 'en', to: 'fr' })
        .then(res => { row[1] = res.text})
    console.log(row) // this shows that I succesfully wait for and get the values
    done(null, row)
})
```

See the url below

https://csv.js.org/transform/options/

The result

```sh
$ node index.js && cat test-output
[ '7228', 'Pot de café en acier inoxydable', '17.26' ]
[ '5010',
  'Set de 4 bidons avec couvercle PS (acier inoxydable)',
  '19.92' ]
[ '7229', 'Cafetière pour 6 tasses (acier inoxydable)', '19.07' ]
"7228";"Pot de café en acier inoxydable";"17.26"
"5010";"Set de 4 bidons avec couvercle PS (acier inoxydable)";"19.92"
"7229";"Cafetière pour 6 tasses (acier inoxydable)";"19.07"
```

Comment: A question, if I may: what is expected as the 1rst arg to the callback, when passed?  A reference to the caller?  And to what does that correspond in the Stream API? (Or is it merely a thing of csv.js's transform to be passed a 2-args callback?)

Comment: The first parameter is usually an error if any. Since we are not failing the call, we pass the first parameter as null and the second one as the actual value. That's how callbacks work in NodeJS